# Uniform convergence of $\frac{y/(2N)}{\sin(y/(2N))}$ towards 1

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I can't come up with a proof, why $f_N(y) := \frac{\frac{y}{2N}}{\sin\left(\frac{y}{2N}\right)}$  converges uniformly against $1$ for $y\in(0,\pi),\ N\to\infty$.

I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: One idea is to use $x-x^3/6 \leq \sin(x) \leq x$ which holds for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Ian.Want to post an answer with your idea?

Comment: What do you mean by $y/2N$? $\frac{y}{2N}$ or $\frac{y}{2}N$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net For the result to be as they say it must be the former...

Comment: Can you prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}=1$? Consider what that means.

Comment: @Ian Don't we need an inequality that holds for $-\pi < x < +\pi$ when we invert $\sin(x)$? Because $\csc$ has poles at $\pm \pi$.

Comment: @Ian Agree, but better to clarify!

Comment: @Ian Yes, I know. Sorry. Let me ask my question better. The inequality you suggested is for $\sin(x)$. How do you use it for $\csc(x)$? I think we need an inequality for $\csc(x)$ that tells us how to control $\csc(x)$ when we get close to its pole at $\pi$.

Comment: @stressedout The poles are nowhere to be seen here, even when $N=1$, because of the $2$. $1-x^2/6 \leq \sin(x)/x \leq 1$ simply becomes $1 \leq x/\sin(x) \leq \frac{1}{1-x^2/6}$ which is valid for $0<x<\sqrt{6}$, and $\pi/2<\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: @Ian Oh, OK. Thanks. Sorry for being confused.

Answer (score 0):

**A solution using [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem)**

The $f_n$ can be extended by continuity at $0$ by raising $f_n(0)=1$. Hence, we can consider the continuous extended maps on the compact interval $[0,\pi]$.

For $n \ge 2$ the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded below by a constant strictly positive. Hence proving the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ is equivalent to the proof of the uniform convergence of $(1/f_n)$. And this is provided by Dini's theorem as for all $x \in [0, \pi]$ the sequence $(1/f_n(x))$ is increasing.